# Inserting an element in a 1D array at the first position

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I was asked this question in a `Javascript` interview and sadly, I couldnt come up with a better answer than the obvious one at that time: Creating a new array, assigning new value to the first location and copying the rest.

What would be the best algorithm in terms of time and space complexity for inserting an element in a 1D array at the first position?

EDIT: No built-in functions like `unshift()`, `splice()`, `push()` and all are to be used.

Comment: So you didn't go though R&D after interview ..

Comment: if you do not need to preserve original order of array then add first element to end of array and after that copy new element to first position

Comment: @FuzzyTree I saw `unshift()` does what we need, but not inbuilt function was expected by the interviewer.

Comment: Why not just make a new array with the first element, the use a for loop to add all the others to it? Or is there a shorter way with no built in functions?

Comment: What about storing the first element into a temp variable, set the first position to the new value and then append the temp value to the end, since I imagine order doesn't matter in this case?

Comment: `[element].concat(array)`, or is `concat` forbidden?

Comment: @DavidFenko and Chase: Thats exactly what I answered in the interview but the interviewer didnt seem to be happy with that.

Comment: Anyway it was a phone interview so I dont really know how they reacted.

Comment: You gotta love these interview questions :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the task is to simply insert an element at the head of a vanilla 1D array, then I think pretty much your only option is this O(N) approach:

```
for(var i = ary.length; i > 0; i--) {
    ary[i] = ary[i - 1];
}
ary[0] = value;
```

If the objective is to optimize the operation of inserting elements at the beginning of arrays (as in, there is a need to do that operation a lot), what you can do is create a data structure that maintains an array with empty space at the beginning and end, and the locations of the first and last populated items:

```
_ _ b d f a _ _ 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

This allows you to insert and delete items at the beginning and end of your data structure in O(1) amortized time, simply by updating the index of the start or end and inserting the value in the next empty location, though the worst-case space usage is 2N.

When the beginning or end of the array fills up, create a new array with double the size of the previous one, and copy the values of the old array to the middle of the new one.

I don't know if that fits within the constraints of your interview question, but a lot of interview questions are more about testing your ability to think about problems, and your knowledge about algorithms, and less about producing the one right answer.

Comment: It seems what I answered was the best answer.

Comment: The OP specifically asked for the inserted value to be the first in the set.  A space is still a character (i.e., a *value*).

Comment: @monners The data structure I'm describing would keep track of the beginning and end of the data and provide access to the data accordingly (hiding the implementation details). As I already said, I'm not sure whether that is within the bounds of the interviewer's expectations, which weren't stated with much detail, but if we're limited to using an ordinary, filled array, then there isn't much room for introspection.

Answer (score 3):

```
var myArr = [0, 1, 2];

function spliceToStart (value, inArray) {
    for (count = inArray.length; count > 0; count--) {
        inArray[count] = inArray[count-1];
    }
    inArray[0] = value;
};

spliceToStart('Value', myArr);
console.log(myArr);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WwL94/1/)

Comment: It looks like you've devised a really convoluted way to do [something simple](http://jsfiddle.net/WwL94/2/) and your code has a bug in it. Why are those `if` statements inside the loop (and why do you need `if` statements at all)? Why do you need a break statement? Why do you need to reduce the length of `myArr` at the end? How is this any better than the four-line approach I provided?

Comment: Was a quick first attempt.  See edit for a much cleaner version.

Comment: Yes, much cleaner now. :)

Answer (score 2):

A functional way to insert an element into an array @ position 0:

```
(function (val) { 
  var i = this.length; 
  while (i--){ this[i+1] = this[i]; };
  this[0] = val; 
}).call([1,2,3,4], 0); //=> [0,1,2,3,4]
```

Another (slightly faster)

```
(function (val) {
    this.reverse()[this.length] = val;
    return this.reverse();
}).call([1,2,3,4], 0); //=> [0,1,2,3,4]
```

[**jsFiddle** example](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/jqH2D/)

Answer (score 1):

> > What would be the best algorithm in terms of time and space complexity for inserting an element in a 1D array at the first position?

**Ordered** - O(n)

```
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
    arr[i+1] = arr[i];

arr[0] = value;
```

**Unordered** - O(1)

```
arr[arr.length] = arr[0];
arr[0] = value;
```

**Ordered** - O(1)

```
arr[arr.length] = value;

// access ith item
arr[(arr.length-i-1)]

// print all items in order
for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
    console.log( arr [ (arr.length-i-1) ] );
```

In this example, the array `arr` is **reveresed**, meaning you consider the last item in the array as the first one. :)

Comment: Is it possible to do better than `O(n)` in the ordered manner?

Comment: @RahulDesai Check it now

Comment: The array order will not be preserved when we reverse the array.

Comment: @RahulDesai actually it's preserved, you will access it this way `arr[(arr.length-i-1)]`

Answer (score 0):

Many people have offered solutions which are basically 'shift everything, then replace the first element'. Perhaps a better way to think about the task is recursively 'insert the element at pos[0], then insert the old value at the first position in the rest of the array'.

We can write it iteratively like this:

```
function prepend(array, value) {
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var old = array[i];
        array[i] = value;
        value = old;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

How about this:

```
<script>
var element = 1;
var array = [2, 3, 4, 5];
array = element + array;
alert(array[0]); //Prints 1
</script>
```

Not sure what this does in the background to be honest, but it seems to add the element to the beginning.

Comment: It actually changes the array to `12,3,4,5`. Check out `console.log(array)`. Its concatenating `element` and `array[0]`.

Comment: Yes, `element + array` is performing string concatenation. Just try running this code with `50` as the value for `element`.